# Custom image in footer (Prestashop)

Tags: image, prestashop, footer

I have a small question. I am using prestashop, and would like to add image in my footer. I am trying to add img tag in footer.tpl

```
<img src="/htdocs/themes/warehouse/img/logo_btm.png" alt="logo" />
```

but instead of picture i have question mark.

Comment: Maybe the path of these img is wrong. Check this, or use the absolute path.

Comment: It's definitely wrong, **htdocs** is not visible to the public. Try `/themes/warehouse/img/logo_btm.png`

Answer (score 0):

you use relative path
instead of relative path use full url to your image like
http://domain.com/link/to/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have to use smarty global var, put the image in your theme's image folder and use this syntax

```
<img src="{$img_dir}logo_btm.png" alt="logo" />
```